# cloud functions dependency in Android failing gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-functions

When I add firebase-function dependency to my module gradle (sorry guys for the long post:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'
```

after syncing project it gives this errors:

[image]

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
//    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

when I am removing comments on this

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
```

it gives this errors on gradle sync:

[image]

Comment: Did you add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file? see [more info here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: @Vall0n Yes i have add it in my module gradle